# How to configure custom LDAP in Grafana helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, ldap, grafana, kubernetes-helm

I'm a newbie at Kubernetes and Helm, trying to customise stable/grafana Helm chart (https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/grafana) with my own LDAP. What's the difference between `auth.ldap` part of `grafana.ini` and `ldap` section of chart's `values.yaml` file? How can I configure LDAP host address and credentials?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To enable LDAP configuration on Grafana. You need to update both parts.

In values.yaml, there are two sections of *grafana.ini* and *ldap*.  To enable LDAP you need to update both sections. Check below:

First *grafana.ini*

```
grafana.ini:
  paths:
    data: /var/lib/grafana/data
    logs: /var/log/grafana
    plugins: /var/lib/grafana/plugins
    provisioning: /etc/grafana/provisioning
  analytics:
    check_for_updates: true
  log:
    mode: console
  grafana_net:
    url: https://grafana.net
## LDAP Authentication can be enabled with the following values on grafana.ini
## NOTE: Grafana will fail to start if the value for ldap.toml is invalid
   auth.ldap:
     enabled: true
     allow_sign_up: true
     config_file: /etc/grafana/ldap.toml
```

Here in grafana.ini part, first enable the auth.ldap to true and specify the configuration file as ldap.toml

Second, *ldap*

```
## Grafana's LDAP configuration
## Templated by the template in _helpers.tpl
## NOTE: To enable the grafana.ini must be configured with auth.ldap.enabled
ldap:
  enabled: true
  # `existingSecret` is a reference to an existing secret containing the ldap configuration
  # for Grafana in a key `ldap-toml`.
  existingSecret: ""
  # `config` is the content of `ldap.toml` that will be stored in the created secret
   config: |-
     verbose_logging = true

     [[servers]]
     host = "my-ldap-server"
     port = 636
     use_ssl = true
     start_tls = false
     ssl_skip_verify = false
     bind_dn = "uid=%s,ou=users,dc=myorg,dc=com"
```

In this part, the helm prepares the ldap.toml file using the LDAP configuration, that is specified in the first step.

Thus update the LDAP host, port, bind_dn as per configurations.

Comment: I am newbie to Grafana set up and trying to understand how I can use secret data for 'bind_password' and other sensitive data, so that it will be set propery in ldap-toml key during install process, any clues since it's not clear to me?

Comment: Tried this config and all I see is out of box LDAP sections in Grafana container's /etc/grafana/ldap.toml file, than what's given in config: |- section of the values.xml, any clues?

Comment: note yaml is the worst and `grafana.ini` is not the same as `grafana: \n  init`